# How do I SELECT a "fake" column/value based on joined table values?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, inner-join

**Short Version:**

I need to customize the result of a query, using one value as the column name, and another value as the column's value. It also needs to be automatic (not hard coded, hundreds of possible "meta keys").

**Long Version:**

I'm using Wordpress's "user meta" structure, where a single user has a user ID, and another table contains "meta-data" which is related to the user.

This meta data is arbitrary, and only has four columns:

`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`.

I would like to do an SQL query for a certain user, and format the results so that all of the metadata is formatted as if they were rows, where the `meta_key` is a column name, and `meta_value` is the value for the column.

---

**Example database:**

```
-- wp_users
* ID    | username | email
35      | radgh    | radgh@example.org

-- wp_usermeta
* meta_id | user_id | meta_key   | meta_value
1         | 35      | first-name | Radley
2         | 35      | last-name  | Sustaire
3         | 35      | newsletter | on
```

**My Query** (I need the (???) portion figured out, which would generate the meta key/value pairs as fake columns)

```
 SELECT 
    `users`.ID as 'user_id',
    `users`.username as 'username',
    `users`.email as 'email',
    (???)

 FROM `wp_users` `users`
     INNER JOIN `wp_usermeta` `meta`
     ON `users`.ID = `meta`.user_id

 WHERE `wp_users`.ID = 35
```

**Desired Outcome:**

```
* user_id | username | email             | first-name | last-name | newsletter
35        | radgh    | radgh@example.org | Radley     | Sustaire  | on
```

In this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730873/wordpress-users-and-usermeta-joining-multiple-rows-in-one-table-to-one-row-in?rq=1) the selected answer uses hard coded fields. I would like to do this automatically. :)

Comment: Take the 'myfakecolumn' and also try to apply this logic. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091330/sql-server-convert-columns-to-rows][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091330/sql-server-convert-columns-to-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has no pivot function. If you know already all of the possible values of meta_key, you could use a hard-coded query like this:

```
SELECT
  wp_users.*,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key`='first-name' THEN meta_value END) AS `first-name`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key`='last-name' THEN meta_value END) AS `last-name`,
  ....
FROM
  wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta
  ON wp_users.ID=wp_usermeta.user_id
GROUP BY
  wp_users.ID, wp_users.username, wp_users.email;
```

Or you could create your SQL query dynamically, using a prepared statement, like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT wp_users.*,',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        'MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key`=\'',
        meta_key,
        '\' THEN meta_value END) AS `',
        meta_key,
        '`')),
    ' FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID=wp_usermeta.user_id',
    ' GROUP BY wp_users.ID, wp_users.username, wp_users.email')
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT meta_key FROM wp_usermeta) s
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3937a/1).

Comment: I gave it a thought and could use two queries, one which gathers all possible meta-keys, then use PHP to build the second query like your example #1. However, I just played with #2 and created a new row, and it seems to work just like I wanted to begin with. Although it is a bit hard to read ;). Would there be a major benefit to option #1 versus #2? I suspect #2 will be making many SELECT queries, but performance is not required here - this script won't be used regularly.

Comment: I couldn't get the second option to work with HeidiSQL (not that the application matters), on MySQL 5.1.54. No need to debug it though, as I ended up going with option #1 using my idea from the last comment. In fact, the plugin (for wordpress) which stored these fields had a global variable with all the field names, so in the end I didn't even need an extra query, and don't have to worry about all the unecessary fields - only what is currently available. In the end, I think this was the best option anyway. Thank you for the sample queries!

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Solution for dynamic columns (meta data) in MySQL via simple/complex query is AFAIK impossible to achive (like other great function like `PIVOT` MySQL is missing). The only way I think is static definition or [MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html), which fetch from meta table possible attributes and build proper query.

Please look at [What is best performance for Retrieving MySQL EAV results as Relational Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764290/what-is-best-performance-for-retrieving-mysql-eav-results-as-relational-table)

Also read about EAV design (pros/cons) on stack [Entity-Attribute-Value Table Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779252/entity-attribute-value-table-design)

Comment: So much jargon to learn, it's no wonder I had so much trouble trying to find similar questions! I'll do some research about this, thank you! Since it may be impossible, perhaps doing a separate query just to find each meta key and then using PHP to format it in a "hard-coded" layout would be the way to go.